# bash script for sorting branches by commit's date with 2 tables

Tags: git, bash

I need very interesting bash & git script
may be someone has it already

check branches in git and sort them like this

1. if commits older than 1 week ( show them)

separator

2. else commit older than 2 weeks (show them)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is very similar to the script below.
Extract the information you need from the log & the commits and print it out in the desired way you want it.

---

Here is a script which do similar thing to what you are asking.
Use it to build your own script.

```
for ref in $(git branch -a); do git log -n1 $ref --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%an%Creset %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)%cr%Creset%n" ; done | cat | sort -n -k1,1
```

#### What does the script does?

```bash
# define a loop variable named ref
for ref in

# execute the desired bash command.
# in this case loop over all the branches - must begin with the $(...)
$(git branch -a)

# The loop content
do 

# get the log entry (first one and extract the desired data from it)

# get the latest commit from the given branch (only 1 commit) 
git log -n1 

# extract the desired data and highlight the info with colors
#
# %an = author name
# %d  = ref names (branch name in our case)
# %cr = committer date, relative
pretty=format:"%Cgreen%an%Creset %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)%cr%Creset%n"

# finish the loop 
done ;

# print out the data after sorting it based upon selected column
| cat | sort -n -k1,1
```

---

To filter dates you can use the

> `--since=<date>`
>   `--after=<date>`
>
> Show commits more recent than a specific date.
>
> `--until=<date>`
>   `--before=<date>`
>
> Show commits older than a specific date.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have seen this example but the output must be separated . And the script has to be adjustable with weeks limits

Comment: Np, 2 separate outputs = function which get parameter and print out in a sorted way.

Comment: `for ref in $(git branch -a ); do git log -n1 $ref --pretty=format:"%Cgreen %cr %Creset%n" ; done | cat | sort -n -k1,1` this for example will sort it by date.

Comment: fatal: bad flag '--pretty=format:%Cgreen %cr %Creset%n' used after filename
fatal: bad flag '--pretty=format:%Cgreen %cr %Creset%n' used after filename
fatal: bad flag '--pretty=format:%Cgreen %cr %Creset%n' used after filename

Comment: You must have `"` before and after the format string. you missed it. place it before the first `%` and also at the end.